# What is the Google Sheets formula that is equivalent to Apps Script Date.parse(value)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Apps Script I have the following:
`Date.parse(s2values[k][DOB_COL])`

...where `s2values[k][DOB_COL]` resolves to a date of birth eg. `Sun Jun 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`

In this example, Date.parse returns `1370127600000` which I then use to create an unique ID by adding another value to it.

I want to do the equivalent to `Date.parse` in a Google Sheet using formula, rather than in script.  I have explored different ways of doing this with TO_DATE and EPOCHTODATE (amongst others) without getting close.

How best to achieve this?

---

Where G2 = date 02/06/2013 (2nd June 2013)

`=VALUE(EPOCHTODATE(TO_DATE(G2),2))` = 25569.00047

`=VALUE(TO_DATE(G2))` = 41427

For script `Date.parse(date)` = 1370127600000  - this is the expected result.